# JasperReports Server says the report is empty

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I've made a very simple pie chart in *Jaspersoft Studio* but I can't see my report in *JasperReports Server*.

I'm using a query like:

```sql
SELECT   city.city_name,count(*) from person inner join city on person.city_id=city.city_id group by city_name
```

Then i used `city.city_name` as the key identifier & count(*) as as a determiner for the size of each slice.
I previewed the report and everything was fine.
Then i save my report as A_4.jrxml & after that I clicked the button "publish report to JasperReports Server"
The dialogue box asked me to choose the folder on the *JR Server* that i want my report to be placed. I select "reports" folder and clicked next. Then the dialogue box asked me to select the data source to use & i chose local data source. I even tried "don't use any data source". I click finish but after all when i click on my report in *JR Server* it says "the reports is empty"
I don't know what the problem is

Comment: buy the way sorry for my bad english

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized

Comment: make sure the User that the data-source is using is the same as the one you are testing(previewing) with, also that the database is the same.